# Jupyter can't run from Sagemath 9.0

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sage

I'm using Ubunto 20.04.06 as operative system.
And use Sagemath 9.0 with Python 3.8.10
I try to install Spyder but don't work.
So when I try to star Jupyter from Sagemath with the following command:

```
sage -n jupyter
```

I get the following menssage:

```
│ SageMath version 9.0, Release Date: 2020-01-01                     │
│ Using Python 3.8.10. Type "help()" for help.                       │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Please wait while the Sage Jupyter Notebook server starts...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/repl/ipython_kernel/install.py", line 314, in have_prerequisites
    from notebook.notebookapp import NotebookApp
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 78, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import Session
  File "/home/jorge/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .asynchronous import AsyncKernelClient
  File "/home/jorge/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
  File "/home/jorge/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/client.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..channels import AsyncZMQSocketChannel, HBChannel
  File "/home/jorge/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/channels.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.utils import ensure_async
ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_async' from 'jupyter_core.utils' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jupyter_core/utils/__init__.py)

The Jupyter notebook requires ssl, even if you do not use
https. Install the openssl development packages in your system and
then rebuild Python (sage -f python3).
```

Then I tried to reinstall Sagemath and Jupyter and always the same message.

I'll be gratefull for any help about find a solution to Sagemath running into Jupyter

Comment: Note that sage 9.0 is *very obsolete*, and sage 10.1 is available.